# Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

What is wrong here? I'm trying to make it work but I get that error in the header. I have included the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `app.component.html` that is being `templateUrl` called by the `app.component.ts`, still no luck.

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }        from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }          from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { TopnavComponent } from './components/navbars/topnav/topnav.component';
import { LeftnavComponent } from './components/navbars/leftnav/leftnav.component';
import { LeftnavsecondaryComponent } from './components/navbars/leftnav-secondary/leftnav-secondary.component';
import { WorldofwarcraftComponent } from './components/games/worldofwarcraft/worldofwarcraft.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:    [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule ],
    declarations:   [ AppComponent, TopnavComponent, LeftnavComponent, LeftnavsecondaryComponent, WorldofwarcraftComponent ],
    bootstrap:  [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule }              from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';

import { WorldofwarcraftComponent } from './components/games/worldofwarcraft/worldofwarcraft.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'worldofwacraft', component: WorldofwarcraftComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Sounds like there is a cyclical dependency somewhere.

Comment: can you add plnkr of your code

Answer (score 141):

I got the same error , sometimes this issue occur and you only need to re-run the server using `ng serve` or whatever CLI you use , as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/1756)

Comment: FWIW, same with Ionic.

Comment: Great. I was stuck from last one hour, and finally got it by re-run ng-serve.

Comment: I still did not get it, what would have caused to have such error to pop up in first place?

Comment: Excellent find, but why does this happen?

Comment: restart the server : ng serve to resolve this issue.Working solution in angular 6

Answer (score 105):

I faced the same error and I discovered the reason.
The reason was two commas    ,, in any array (for example: `imports` property) like this.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  CommonModule, FormsModule,,
]})
```

Comment: This problem comes when you generate components using angular cli.

Answer (score 10):

Try this may help you: 
Stop and Start the `ng-serve` service.
Now the page could navigate.

Answer (score 5):

It was caused because I repeated the export in one of my index.ts file:

Answer (score 4):

This is a very annoying and difficult to understand error. I did a file comparison using Araxis Merge found every file in my two projects were almost identical at first glance. However, after further review I noticed a slight difference in file structure(which I wasn't really looking for at first, rather I was looking for configuration differences) that my second project had generated a js file from one of the ts files.

As you can see **on the left side** there is a js file. The right side project showed my node-builder component and ran without error. The right side was what caused the problem.

[image: Extra unneeded file]

Webpack had picked up that Javascript file and tried to package it. Obviously, when Webpack encountered the ts version it transpiled it into a duplicate js file, thus creating a confusing run-time exception.

```
t {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the 
module 'AppModule'
    at t.m (http://localhost:……}
```

As you can see this problem had nothing to do with configuration as many posts had led me to believe. As stated above your problem may have to do with configuration but in my case it did not.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, on app.module.ts ( Ionic 3 )

```
providers: [
    , StatusBar
    , SplashScreen
```

Changed to:

```
providers: [
     StatusBar
    , SplashScreen
```

And works.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171978/4051181) suggesting re-running `ng serve`, but that wasn't relevant for my situation as I have the app permanently running in IIS. In my case, I had built with `ng build --watch`, but stopping that and re-running it fixed the problem. I assume something was built incorrectly when it was an incremental build, but doing the full build fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was due to build issue. may be you have added some components or other things in your App module and forgot to rebuild it. So in the browser Angular is not able to recognize your fresh entries in app module because build is required to register them properly. So for development mode kill the current server and use ng serve.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was class name diffrent and the name i.e in between { name } exported in app.mdoule.ts was diffrent

good luck

Comment: This is the same answer as @Alexander Zaldostanov, just more generalized, so I would have made it an edit or a comment on that post (I know you may not have the privilege yet, sorry).

Answer (score 1):

In My scenario, I made mistake like below

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class NewTestRoutingModule {
  static component : [NewTestContainerComponent, NewTestInletComponent, NewTestStructureComponent]
}
```

and in Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LayersRoutingModule.component],
```

The components array in Routing should be like this.

```
 static component = [NewTestContainerComponent, NewTestInletComponent, NewTestStructureComponent]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, in `@Component` I wrote selector: `all-employees` and in `app.module.ts` module it was `<all- employees></all- employees>`

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this with Angular 2 and it turns out it has something to do with imports and relative paths, if you're exporting something in from the same location

For instance when using barrels, explicitly specify the `./`

```
export * from './create-profile.component';
```

instead of

```
export * from 'create-profile.component';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@8.2.14/bundles/compiler.umd.js (2603:26)
>   Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'

I had the problem that `export class someClassName` had used an unknown/wrong class name in one of my files (copy/paste error) and has been never registered anywhere (e.g. `AppModule.ts*).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I mistakenly put `TestBed.configureTestingModule` outside of a `beforeEach` block.