# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular

am getting following error like Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'.
I have imported all the modules correctly. But still, it showing the same error.  Can anyone give the solution?

[screenshot for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2fR5.png)

my code is,

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.component';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
ProductListComponent
],
imports: [ 
BrowserModule
], 
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

product-list.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
 selector:`pm-products`,
 templateUrl:'./product-list.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
 })

export class ProductListComponent {
pageTitle: string='Product List';
}
```

Comment: create stack blitz (https://stackblitz.com/)  please.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwofjt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: remove this line from product-list.component.ts file styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']

Comment: `./product-list.component.css` is not included in your project but you are including it in your styleUrls

Comment: I have added that file.

Comment: I have edited the code again.. plz kindly check this url

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwofjt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @swetha would this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560510/unexpected-value-undefined-declared-by-the-module-appmodule

Answer (score 1):

In index.html, change the selector to `<pm-root>`. Angular bootstraps your `app.component` at startup as shown in `app.module`. In your app.component, you have your selector as `<pm-root>` but in index.html, it is `<my-app>`. No component with such selector exists so you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ygnnd)

You should add `product-list.component.css`

Because You have specified in `styleUrls`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:`pm-products`,
    templateUrl:'./product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})

export class ProductListComponent {
     pageTitle: string='Product List';
}
```

Comment: index.html  add ---> <my-app>loading</my-app>

Comment: please refer my demo.